# In tableview Data is Overwriting

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have two `collectionView`. One is main and second is sub items
when i click both collectionView the data is added in `tableView`.

My requirement is like when I click on first `collectionView` it will be added in cart and `tableViewCell` should display it original price which I retrieve from web service.

Now when I click on second `collectionView` it should also added to tableview but when I click this it will have to display price as 0. 
To add into tableview i am using did select method of `collectionView`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let  dictSub = arr[indexPath.row] as! [String : AnyObject]
    //to insert product to top of tableview
    arrTable(dictSub, atIndex: 0)
    self.tbl.reloadData()
}
```

At `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I am checking that `isMainProduct` equals to one or zero

code :

```
if  isFromMain == "1" {
    let Price   = NSString(string: pPrice1).floatValue
    let total   = 1 * Price
    cell.lbl.text = String(format: "%.2f", total)
} else {
    let Price   = 0.00
    let total   = 1 * Price
    cell.lbl.text = String(format: "%.2f", total)
}
```

When one it will add original price but when it is not from main product it will display zero.

Issue is:

First when i click on main collection view original price is displayed but when i clicked on sub items price of main product also changes to  zero.

I want to prevent this data overwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`you are adding `Dictionary`to `Array`, you can use this `Dictionary` to differentiate that it is coming from main collectionView or not instead of setting instance value of `isFromMain` to `1`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var  dictSub = arr[indexPath.row] as! [String : AnyObject]  
    if collectionView == mainCollectionView {
        dictSub["isFromMain"] = "1"
    }
    else {
        dictSub["isFromMain"] = "0"
    }
    arrTable(dictSub, atIndex: 0)
    self.tbl.reloadData()
}
```

Now use this key to in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to check it is coming from main `CollectionView` or from second one.

```
let dic = arrTable[indexPath.row] as! [String : AnyObject]
let isFromMain = dic["isFromMain"] as! String
if  isFromMain == "1" {
    let Price   = NSString(string: pPrice1).floatValue
    let total   = 1 * Price
    cell.lbl.text = String(format: "%.2f", total)
} else {
    let Price   = 0.00
    let total   = 1 * Price
    cell.lbl.text = String(format: "%.2f", total)
}
```

Comment: really helps me bro. thank you very much. i am grateful to you

Comment: Just want to know how to think broad ? :)

Comment: You will, and also SO is available to help you :)

Comment: one thing more. how to calculate total behalf of this code

Comment: Actually this price calculation i have to do total price.

Comment: That you can do in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`method of collectionView, get the price of that item, declare one instance for totalPrice and add its value with price in didSelect of collectionView.

Comment: total is textfield
can you plz edit answer with price code?

Comment: I am not talking about that total that you have used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, i am telling you to declare new instance at class level for incrementing your total value with selected item price inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, If it is possible please add this as new question on SO with more detail about what you want with total and with new code, if i am i able to give answer i will give.

Comment: Batter to add new one, because this question may help to one who come with same problem.

Comment: i am stuck in this issue.please help me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327000/in-collectionview-how-to-set-colors-according-to-selection

Comment: Can you plz go through this issue ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342311/receipt-alignment-is-not-working-properly-in-swift

Comment: Hi bro.i am stuck in one issue.can you help?

Comment: Sure,  add question here, I will check and give answer if I'm able to

Comment: question is already here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327611/how-to-delete-all-items-if-i-delete-one-of-them-in-tableview

Comment: it is related to this question.